# Como guardar código HTML en ORACLE usando PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, oracle

Estoy enviando codigo HTML por medio de AJAX en formato JSON y me esta mandando este error:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  oci_bind_by_name(): Invalid variable used for bind in <b>D:\PHPTest\wsFSupervision\sistema2\pages\php\puntosDAO.php</b> on line <b>459</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound in <b>D:\PHPTest\wsFSupervision\sistema2\pages\php\puntosDAO.php</b> on line <b>460</b><br />
```

**Este es mi método en donde envío el HTML a la base de datos**

```
public function guardar_frontEnd($str_html) {
    $conexion = conex::con();
    $stid1 = oci_parse($conexion, 'begin SP_INSERTAR_FRONTEND(:x1); end;');
    oci_bind_by_name($stid1, ':x1', $str_html);
    $result = oci_execute($stid1);
    oci_free_statement($stid1);
    if ($result == 1) {
        return true;
    } else if ($result == "") {
        return false;
    }
    OCILogoff($conexion);
}
```

**El procedimiento almacenado**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERTAR_FRONTEND(p_str_html IN VARCHAR2)
AS

str_html CLOB := p_str_html;

v_count number;

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM TBLPRUEBA;

    IF (v_count = 0) THEN  
       INSERT INTO TBLPRUEBA(ID_ACORDEON, DESCRIP_ACORDEON) VALUES(1, 'NO HAY PREGUNTAS');
    ELSIF (v_count > 1) THEN
       UPDATE TBLPRUEBA T SET T.DESCRIP_ACORDEON = str_html WHERE T.ID_ACORDEON = 2;
    ELSE
       INSERT INTO TBLPRUEBA VALUES(2, str_html);
       COMMIT;
    END IF;
END;
```

**JQUERY**

```
let frontEnd;
frontEnd = $(this).prev()[0];
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "iajax_configuracion_acordeon.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      nivelJSON: JSON.stringify(nivel),
      subnivelJSON: JSON.stringify(subnivel),
      preguntasJSON: JSON.stringify(preguntas),
      cantSubnivelxNivelJSON: JSON.stringify(cantSubnivelxNivel),
      cantPregxSubnivelJSON: JSON.stringify(cantPregxSubnivel),
      cantPregxNivelJSON: JSON.stringify(cantPregxNivel),
      frontEndJSON: JSON.stringify(frontEnd) /*Aquí lo envio por medio de AJAX*/
    },
    dataType: "text",
    .....
  });
```

**El HTML que quiero almacenar es este:**

Nota: Cuando guardo se almacena de esta manera

```
<div class="contenedor-panel"><div class="contenedor-panel-hijo"><div class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p><div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="rejilla" title="Obtener solo una unica tabla de preguntas" src="https://img.icons8.com/small/20/000000/table-1.png"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" title="Editar" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"><img class="img-panel-ficha" title="Eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto" style="display: none;"><div contenteditable="false" class="panel-aspecto-descripcion"><p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_aspecto_descripcion</p><div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"><img class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores"><div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas"><div class="puntaje"><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div></div><div class="observacion"><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i">i</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div></div><div class="pregunta"><form class="pregunta-contenedor"><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial" contenteditable="true">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA</div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox"><select class="comboBox" disabled=""><option value="Vacio" selected="">--Seleccione--</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarPregunta" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></form></div><input class="btn-pregunta" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA PREGUNTA"></div></div><input class="btn-categoria" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA CATEGORIA"></div></div><div class="contenedor-panel-hijo"><div class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p><div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="rejilla" title="Obtener solo una unica tabla de preguntas" src="https://img.icons8.com/small/20/000000/table-1.png"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" title="Editar" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"><img class="img-panel-ficha" title="Eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto" style="display: none;"><div contenteditable="false" class="panel-aspecto-descripcion"><p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_aspecto_descripcion</p><div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"><img class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores"><div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas"><div class="puntaje"><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div></div><div class="observacion"><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i">i</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div></div><div class="pregunta"><form class="pregunta-contenedor"><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial" contenteditable="true">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA</div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox"><select class="comboBox" disabled=""><option value="Vacio" selected="">--Seleccione--</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarPregunta" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></form></div><input class="btn-pregunta" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA PREGUNTA"></div></div><input class="btn-categoria" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA CATEGORIA"></div></div><div class="contenedor-panel-hijo"><div class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p><div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="rejilla" title="Obtener solo una unica tabla de preguntas" src="https://img.icons8.com/small/20/000000/table-1.png"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" title="Editar" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"><img class="img-panel-ficha" title="Eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto" style="display: none;"><div contenteditable="false" class="panel-aspecto-descripcion"><p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_aspecto_descripcion</p><div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"><img class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores"><div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas"><div class="puntaje"><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div></div><div class="observacion"><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i">i</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div></div><div class="pregunta"><form class="pregunta-contenedor"><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial" contenteditable="true">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA</div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox"><select class="comboBox" disabled=""><option value="Vacio" selected="">--Seleccione--</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i" disabled=""></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarPregunta" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></form></div><input class="btn-pregunta" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA PREGUNTA"></div></div><input class="btn-categoria" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA CATEGORIA"></div></div></div>
```

**Por último:**

Me ha llegado a funcionar solo si se envía una cadena simple.

```
frontEnd = "Cadena simple";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta era corregir el jQuery

```
let frontEnd;
frontEnd = $(this).prev().html();
```